# Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'RecyclerView.ViewHolder!'

Tags: android, kotlin

class StudentAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.StudentViewHolder>() {
private var stdList: ArrayList = ArrayList()

```
fun addItems(items: ArrayList<StudentModel>){
    this.stdList = items
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = StudentViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_items_std, parent,false)
)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StudentViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val std = stdList[position]
    holder.bindView(std)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return stdList.size
}

class StudentViewHolder(var view: View): RecyclerView(view){
    private var id = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvId)
    private var name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)
    private var email = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvEmail)
    private var btnDelete = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnDelete)

    fun bindView(std: StudentModel){
        id.text = std.id.toString()
        name.text= std.name.toString()
        email.text = std.email.toString()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your view holder should extend `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)`

```
class StudentViewHolder(var view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    private var id = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvId)
    private var name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)
    private var email = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvEmail)
    private var btnDelete = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnDelete)

    fun bindView(std: StudentModel){
        id.text = std.id.toString()
        name.text= std.name.toString()
        email.text = std.email.toString()
    }
}
```

Here is great [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?gclid=Cj0KCQjw-pCVBhCFARIsAGMxhAfUZl25bNTBdnX4rn1j--8aBw_ltI0NNbydKMdMXjy3SE3TNIf8_j4aAvqrEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) to refer